# Text facing camera with onBeforeRender never renders

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-drei

I want to render text using @react-three/drei, in a way such that the text is always facing the user. Based on other posts on SO, I've found the solution to copy the quaternion of the camera into the text object within a onBeforeRender function.

I've gotten it to work, but there is one thing missing. When I use `onBeforeRender`, nothing shows on screen - i.e. the text box disappears. However, when I use `onAfterRender`, everything works as expected. Another phenomenon I've encountered is that I can get it to work if I comment out `onBeforeRender` when I start the application, and THEN when the text box is shown, I uncomment it. Then the text box will render facing the camera.

Clearly I am doing something wrong that makes the `onBeforeRender` fail to render the object unless it has already been rendered before. Can someone help me spot my mistake?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Text } from '@react-three/drei'

const propTypes = {
  position: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number).isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

const TextBox3d = ({ position, text }) => {
  const ref = useRef()

  const onBeforeRender = (...args) => {
    const camera = args[2]
    ref.current.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion)
    ref.current.frustumCulled = false
    ref.current.updateMatrix(true)
    ref.current.updateWorldMatrix(true, true)
    ref.current.updateMatrixWorld(true)
  }
  return (
    <group
      position={position}
    >
      <Text
        ref={ref}
        color='black'
        anchorX='center'
        anchorY='middle'
        fontSize={0.5}
        // onBeforeRender={onBeforeRender} // <------- Doesn't work!
        onAfterRender={onBeforeRender} // <------- Hack, but works
      >
        {text}
      </Text>
    </group>
  )
}

TextBox3d.propTypes = propTypes

export default TextBox3d
```